# Where did Descartes write, "With me everything turns into mathematics."

Tags: math-history

I have been trying to source a famous quote of Descartes, "Omnia apud me mathematica fiunt." or "With me everything turns into mathematics."

I cannot find a source for this.  The English e-books I have, nor the the Latin version on Google books.

It's scattered all over the web and "turns into mathematics" shows up in Google's N-Gram viewer starting in 1930.  None ever cite the book it came from, let alone the chapter.

Comment: Unsourced and looks like no one can find according to: http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Ren%C3%A9_Descartes

Comment: Just to be clear, given the original quotation in Axel Kemper's answer, what Descartes is actually saying is this:

"[...] according to me, all things in nature occur mathematically."

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Would you mind editing this [Wikiquote page](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes#Quotations)?  I tried filling in the context the best I could, but I do not read French nor German.  Also, me is grammatically incorrect, it should be 'myself' that that sounds clumsy....

Comment: It's gloriously awkward and hasty Latin-to-English translationese, sure, but I don't think it's strictly ungrammatical... In any event, though, an idiomatic translation should be something like "in my opinion, everything in nature occurs mathematically;" I've changed the relevant sentence on the Wikiquote page accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This quote is said to be from a letter of Descartes to Mersenne dated 11th March 1640 (Correspondence 1640  - 1643, page 36, note to line 7). The original sentence was "[...] apud me omnia fiunt Mathematicè in Natura [...]".

A version translated from [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=9Xh3fVZLCycC&pg=PA532&lpg=PA532&dq=%22Omnia%20apud%20me%20mathematica%20fiunt%22%20original%20zitat&source=bl&ots=CgQOrveRiM&sig=WFHwIK20r5vRZ66FwCaxo857LCU&hl=de&sa=X&ei=_Wf2UcHlJYbfsgaf1IHABg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Omnia%20apud%20me%20mathematica%20fiunt%22%20original%20zitat&f=false) along with some discussion regarding the translation can (thanks to this Q/A) be found on [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes#Quotations).

An image of the original page is [online](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Descartes_-_%C5%92uvres,_%C3%A9d._Adam_et_Tannery,_III.djvu/48), but I could not include more than a snippet here:

[image]

Comment: Came back to read this question after getting an SE trophy and, well, this is why I love the internet!  Some random person giving me information that I failed to find after searching through literally millions of books ... it's amazing!